# Why do I have six “High Definition Audio Devices” showing up in my device manager?

Tags: windows-7, audio, device-manager

When I go into my device manager, it appears to redundantly list 6 “High Definition Audio Device.” Is this normal or is something wrong? My motherboard is a [Gigabyte GA-Z97-HD3](http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/GA-Z97-HD3-rev-10#sp).

I am running a brand new install of Windows 7, and I did not install any drivers for the on board audio.

I am also running a PCI sound blaster card, and an external USB audio interface.

My install of Ableton live won’t start, and as part of the troubleshooting, I want to get to the bottom of all of these redundant devices.

I went into BIOS and found no options to disable the onboard audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like pretty standard "movie surround sound" with each "channel" being called a "device" - front right and left, rear right and left, subwoofer and front center.